# Determining sequence of oligoribonucleotide

Tags: molecular-biology, homework, rna, enzymes

> Oligoribonucleotide X was treated with phosphatase (for removal of 3'
>   and 5' - terminal phosphates), then with RNAase T1, which cleaves all
>   phosphodiester bonds located in a 3' position of guanosine in a
>   5'-specific manner. [image]
>
> As a result, oligonucleotides L, M and N were generated in equal
>   amounts. Each of them was further treated with phosphatase and
>   subjected to alkaline hydrolysis. Results are listed in the table
>   below.
>
> [image]
>
> Then experiment was modified: oligoribonucleotide X after treatment
>   with phosphatase was hydrolyzed with RNAaseP, which cleaves all
>   phosphodiester bonds in a 3'-position of pyrimidines in a 5' -
>   specific manner.
>
> [image]
>
> This hydrolysis yielded five products in approximately equimolar
>   concentrations: uridine monophosphate, cytidine monophosphate and
>   oligonucleotides P, Q and R. After resolution of the mixture and
>   alkaline hydrolysis of these oligonucleotides data listed in the table
>   below were obtained.
>
> [image]

My thinking : G can not be at the 5' end otherwise we would get a single Guanosine also in the first experiment. G can also not be at the second last from 3' end as we have not got any singles. We have got A and C in a duplet and so they must have been at the 3' end.

I also have trouble understanding the significance of "mole/mole of oligoribonucleotide".

I am trying to fit  in other results but am unable to do so. 
A GOOD HINT WILL BE APPRECIATED MORE THAN A DIRECT ANSWER.

Thanks

Comment: @Satwik In the above comment - do you mean UMP and CMP ?

Comment: @SatwikPasani And by doublet u don't mean they are 1 after the other because I don't think that is possible.

Comment: @biogirl It's not clear from what you have written so far that you realise the significance of getting a cytidine rather than a CMP in one of the products - it means, for example that you can deduce the sequence of M, which in turn allows you to deduce the sequence of Q.

Comment: @biogirl Did you solve this? If yes, I wanted to know the answer they(the source of the question) provide, to make sure I had the correct solution.

Comment: @SatwikPasani I haven't tried this question again as I was busy in other things. Will ask for your help if I am still not able to do it. The answer to this question has not been given in the source. Thanks.

Comment: @satwik pasani Nope! I am not able to solve it .Please tell me the answer (not the solution as I want to "reverse derive"it !)

Comment: @biogirl I had forgotten my original derivation but I quickly re-derived it. Please check if I have made any errors in haste. $5'-UACGCCGAC-3'$

Comment: @SatwikPasani Thanks a lot : I will "reverse derive it"

Comment: @SatwikPasani ok i have done it. It's right. Thanks a ton !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few hints which might help you:-

1) You get free `UMP` and `CMP` (in contrast to `UMP + C` or `CMP + U`) in the second experiment before alkaline hydrolysis.

2) There are two `CMP` in "N" oligoribonucleotide, and a free cytidine (and not `CMP`) in "M" and "Q".

3)Use the fact that all oligoribonucleotides were treated with phosphatase before being subjected to alkaline hydrolysis.

(Referring to your comment, I dont know why do you think consecutive cytidine is not possible).

These are a few hints that helped me solve this. If you want further clarification or the answer, tell me in the comments.

Answer for reverse derivation:- $5'-UACGCCGAC-3'$